# Adding Linux machine in specific vlan

Tags: linux, ip, fedora, lan

We have one linux machine (Fedora).In our network we have multiple vlan's (Say VLAN-A, VLAN-B, VLAN-C).  By default through dhcp out machine is getting ip from VLAN - A.

Now for some testing We need to configure ip of VLAN-C. But when we are assigning static IP of VLAN-C in machine, it not able to ping/connect other machines of VLAN-C

Is there any way in linux client to assign IP of VLAN-C.

Comment: It's configured on a switch. You have to set an access port of the machine to VLAN-C. Btw. you should have asked on Superuser

Comment: Thanks .... Look like I have to talk with Network team

Answer (score 3):

The vconfig program allows you to create and remove vlan-devices on a vlan enabled kernel. Vlan-devices are virtual ethernet devices which represents the virtual lans on the physical lan.Please note that this is yet another method of configuring VLAN. If you are happy with above method no need to read below.
Add VLAN ID 5 with follwing command for eth0:

## vconfig add eth0 5

The vconfig add command creates a vlan-device on eth0 which result into eth0.5 interface. You can use normal ifconfig command to see device information:

## ifconfig eth0.5

Use ifconfig to assign IP address to vlan interfere :

## ifconfig eth0.5 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255 up

Get detailed information about VLAN interface:

## cat /proc/net/vlan/eth0.5

If you wish to delete VLAN interface delete command:

## ifconfig eth0.5 down

## vconfig rem eth0.5

Comment: Thanks... I tried your solution, its not giving any error but still its not solved my problem

Comment: Thanks. The other examples I've found on the net forget to add the vconfig add eth0 5 step.